# How do I display all author names for papers written by less than 4 authors in my citations?

Tags: citing, natbib, apa-style, apacite

I'm using natbib with the apalike style. I have to stick to this exact style due to publishing requirements.

If I am citing papers with 3 authors or fewer, I need it to display all their names. If more, then I need it to display the first authors name followed by et al.

Things I have tried so far include maxcitenames, citep*, and changing style to apacite.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some of the publishing requirements you're facing simply cannot be satisfied if the `natbib` citation management package and the `apalike` bibliography style have to be employed. Oh, and `maxcitenames` is a `biblatex` option; it will not doing anything meaningful under natbib/apalike. The only way to satisfy the requirement to mention all names if a piece has 3 or fewer authors is to modify the  `apalike` bib style; however, that seems to be ruled out by your publisher. I think you need to go back to your publisher and ask for clarification as to what's really needed here.